How To Have Div Scroll When Out-Of-Bounds, While Using Flex?
I have a main div, which is a child and is centered by a content div. This content div is siblings with a header div and footer div, which are children of a wrapper div. The content div is made to grow and that is what I want so that the content always takes up all the screen besides the header and footer div with their set sizes. And when I shrink thee screen small enough that the main div overflows the screen, which is what I want, I want to be able to scroll it back into the screen, however that does not work fully and it gets cut off. I already have margin on the main div, so that it overflows properly with the header and footer divs. The problem remains no matter what I do.
I've tried to set max/min-width on the content div and a variety of other things, even completely rethinking about how to do it and drawing it out. But I haven't come to a conclusion of how to have the main div scroll back to being visible and not cut off once it clips out.


html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* background:linear-gradient(90deg,#1a1536,rgb(40, 9, 90), rgb(18, 29, 87),#1a1536); */
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  ] white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* HEADER */

#header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-bottom: solid white 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#variant {
  margin-top: -10px;
}


/*CONTENT*/

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  /* max-width:100%;
    min-width:100%; */
}

#main_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 675px;
  width: 1350px;
  background:linear-gradient(aqua, blue,red,purple);
}


/* FOOTER */

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  border-top: solid white 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <h2 class="text" id="map">Map</h2>
      <h1 class="text" id="variant">Variant</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="main_div"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <button class="text" id="return" onclick="index()">Return</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>



